# Insert values into table only if a combination of two id's don't already exist in the table

Tags: sql

I want to insert a bunch of column info into a table.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE 
       (AID, BID, CID, INT) 
SELECT AID, BID, CID 
FROM   ANOTHERTABLE 
WHERE  X
```

I want to add a clause to my insert: where insert only if AID and BID DON'T exist on the same row already.

I can't do a `where != AID` because AID exists in different rows with different BID's on the same row.

I do however need to keep one combination of AIB and BID.

Therefore I just don't want duplicate rows of AIB and BID on the same row.

I tried where `rowA != AID AND rowB != BID` but this means that the first row of AID and BID does not exist in the table. I need only one combination of AID and BID.

Comment: Look into `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

Comment: So AID and BID form a composite key?

Comment: Not really, I just have an interface that shows the user by means of AID and another attribute e.g. training completed in BID, I don't want these to be duplicated in my interface.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29688738/122139

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses `WHERE EXISTS NOT()` to check for the two values in the target table.

If AID or BID can have a NULL value, that should be handled using `ISNULL()`.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE 
    (AID, BID, CID, INT) 
SELECT 
    AID, BID, CID  -- problem here - where is value for INT?
FROM ANOTHERTABLE 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 
            AID, BID
        FROM TABLE
        -- WHERE TABLE.AID & BID ... Wrong (thank you Gareth Lyons)
           WHERE TABLE.AID = ANOTHERTABLE.AID 
             AND TABLE.BID = ANOTHERTABLE.BID
    )
```

Comment: & is NOT a concatenation operator in SQL Server, it's a bitwise comparison. So it'll fail on strings and give incorrect answers on numeric data. Also the datatypes aren't given so you can't know that concatenation will work. Concatenation has other problems too, such as possibly precluding the use of appropriate indexes. Use TABLE.AID = ANOTHERTABLE.AID AND TABLE.BID = ANOTHERTABLE.BID instead.